# Export folder size to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm putting together a script that will import a CSV with a list of folder names (and other fields) to get folder sizes (in this case SamAccountName matches the folder names) and then export to a CSV. I can get the folder sizes but I can't get it to export to the CSV. I'm still learning PS so I'm sure this is ugly to some of you so bear with me.

Source file looks like this:

| SamAccountName | DisplayName | Enabled | HomeDirectory | Office |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test3 | 3, Test | FALSE | \blahblahblah\folderuserhome\subfolder\Name | WASEA |
| test1 | does not exist |  |  |  |

Script:

```
function Count-Size($path)
{
  "{0:N2} KB" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1KB) 
}

Set-Location '\\server04\e$\tempdir'
$FolderName = Import-Csv 'E:\PS_Files\H drive names.csv' 
$FolderOut = 'E:\PS_Files\H drive sizes.csv'

$FolderSize = foreach ($name in $FolderName){
  $DirName = $Name.SamAccountName
  Count-Size $DirName
  }   

$FolderName | Select-Object *,@{Name='FolderSize';Expression={'$FolderSize'}} | Export-Csv $FolderOut -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

This creates the out file and passes through the existing fields but the new "FolderSize" column just has "$FolderSize" entered in the column instead of the actual folder size.

| SamAccountName | DisplayName | Enabled | HomeDirectory | Office | FolderSize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test3 | 3, Test | FALSE | \blahblahblah\folderuserhome\subfolder\Name | WASEA | $FolderSize |
| test1 | does not exist |  |  |  | $FolderSize |

However, in PS I verified $FolderSize contains the data I'm looking for. I thought I could use a variable as an expression but maybe I'm wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be possible you're missing some code? `Count-Size` doesn't seem to be defined here. Is it the script block at the top?

Comment: Sorry - I missed that line when I copied it over. I added it in now but I've had it in the working script.

Comment: Did one of the provided answers solved the problem? If yes, please consider accepting one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can use a [Calculated Property](https://www.bing.com/search?q=calculated+property+powershell&cvid=9bdd13d3d1e949a9813236efc5c31c75&aqs=edge..69i57.6903j0j1&pglt=675&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531) to achieve what you're after. The issue lies with your loop. Regardless if you do get it to work, and changing the quotes to Double Quotes (*for interoplation to occur*), you will get the same size for the each folder; this is due to you not telling PowerShell to do it for each folder and export it per.

- You basically tell PowerShell to get the Size for each and every folder path provided via `SamAccountName`, save all those results to `$FolderSize`.
- Then, you tell it to export using `'$FolderSize'` which won't be interpreted due to the single quotes reading/writing *as is*, and the size would be the same for all folders.

Doing this in one swoop, you end up with:

```
$FolderOut = 'E:\PS_Files\H drive sizes.csv'
Import-Csv -Path 'E:\PS_Files\H drive names.csv' | 
    Select-Object *, @{
        Name = "FolderSize"
        Expression = {
            "{0:N2} KB" -f ((Get-ChildItem -Path $_.SamAccountName -File -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1KB)             
        }
    } #| Export-Csv -Path $FolderOut -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Here, you're  telling PowerShell to query each folder as it comes down the pipeline, do your expression, and pipe it to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Thanks Abraham. This did it.

Comment: @nelsonm, cool man. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Change `'$FolderSize'` to `"$FolderSize"`.

The difference is that double quotes are evaluating the variable before printing, single quotes refer to just text.

Comment: Thanks Erick - this got me closer but now I know about the difference between single and double quotes.